# In what physical situation would the correlation of two spins be useful?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I have done problem 4.50 from Griffiths' Quantum Mechanics (2nd ed), quoted below, and got the correct answer. What would be a physical situation where this would be useful?

I have already had some people tell me to look at Bell's Theorem in Ch 12, which I did. But that is seven chapters ahead of where I am at in the book, and contains things that are over my head at this point. Can anyone tell me, in plain undergrad terms, a physical situation where this would be useful?

> **Problem 4.55** Suppose two spin-$1/2$ particles are known to be in the singlet configuration (Equation 4.178). Let $S_a^{(1)}$ be the component of the spin angular momentum of particle number 1 in the direction defined by the unit vector $\hat{a}$. Similarly, let $S_b^{(2)}$ be the component of 2's angular momentum in the direction $\hat{b}$. Show that
>   $$\langle S_a^{(1)} S_b^{(2)} \rangle = -\frac{\hbar^2}{4}\cos\theta,\tag{4.198}$$
>   where $\theta$ is the angle between $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$.

Comment: So you can think of no systems that exhibit two spin 1/2 particles?

Comment: Yes I can. A hydrogen atom comes to mind. But my question is when would this be useful to use.

Comment: Thanks for another useless question in response to mine though man! Very helpful!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're studying Griffiths' book on Quantum Mechanics. It is interesting that you're asking about this particular exercise, since this is an equation that Griffiths is cross-referencing in the Afterword (Bell's Theorem), which I clearly suggest you go and read, specifically about the Bell inequalities.

This exact problem of orientation selection is what is necessary to do a specific calculation for the proposed experiment to try and probe the (then new) elements of quantum entaglement.

Comment: I'm only in QM 1, I'm an undergrad and my final for this class is in ten days. There are several things that are a bit advanced for me in chapter 12.4, Bell's Theorem. Can you tell me about what physical situations this would be useful for in undergrad terms? I am not quite ready for CH 12 yet...

Comment: I have already done the problem and I have got the right answer, I'd just like to know when it's useful.

Comment: @ZLeach If you think that quantum entanlgement is too hard for you to understand yet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement then have patience and you will see the usefulness of such solutions eventually. quantum computation for example is using entangled states https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing

Comment: @ZLeach You should really read up on Bell inequalities.  The reason they appear in a late chapter is not that more prerequisites are needed, but probably that it is not considered essential for the curriculum.  All you need is the equation you mention and an idea what you mean by "local" and "realistic" theories, for which studying quantum theory for another year does not help either.    A nice derivation of Bell's inequality is contained e.g. in Preskill's lecture notes, http://www.theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/ph229/notes/chap4_01.pdf

Comment: Actually there are a lot of things in that chapter that are way ahead of me and my class, and I don't have time to read that far ahead right now, which I was hoping someone helpful would come along and not speak in riddles. Maybe they could even help instead of just being difficult.